# Possible bug: SparseArray Part assignment loses default value?

Tags: bugs, sparse-arrays

**fixed in 10.0.2**

---

This sure looks like a bug to me (Mathematica 10.0.0, MacOS):

```
(Local) In[345]:= s = SparseArray[{}, {20}, 1]

(Local) Out[345]= SparseArray[< 0 >, {20}, 1]

(Local) In[346]:= s // Normal

(Local) Out[346]= {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

(Local) In[347]:= s[[All]] = 1; s

(Local) Out[347]= SparseArray[< 0 >, {20}]

(Local) In[348]:= s // Normal

(Local) Out[348]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Apparently when I assigned 1 to all elements of s, it correctly realized that everything was still equal to the default, so left everything unspecified. But it incorrectly lost the 1 default value and changed the array to have the default default value of 0.

This is a toy example, but it comes out of a more complicated example in which it is causing me a serious problem. I don't know the full scope of the problem, but it is not necessary to assign to the entire array for the default value to be lost. I guess the lesson is that non-zero defaults are fragile.

Is this really a bug, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: on version 9, I get same thing. I think it has to do with the way you build it in first place. Compare to `data = Table[1, {20}];s = SparseArray[data]; s[[All]] = 1; s // Normal` and now it is ok.

Comment: Yes, but in that case the default value is 0 from the start. Compare to `data = Table[1, {20}]; s = SparseArray[data, Automatic, 1]; s[[All]] = 1; s // Normal`, where the SparseArray is created with default 1. The same problem occurs.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me

Comment: I agree this looks like a bug. I've played with it for a few minutes, and so far the only situation in which this occurs is when I reassign `All` to the default value (reassigning `All` to a non-default value does not lose the default). Can you supply examples of the other situations you mention?

Comment: It's something like this: `gs = SparseArray[{}, {l, m, m}, 1];... Do[{g, c} = PhylogenyCoincidenceIndex[p, seqs[[All, i]], ksyms[[i]], tsi, ts]; gs[[i]] = g;...,{i,l}]`. Sorry I can't format it better. PhylogenyCoincidenceIndex returns an m*m binary matrix. Everything work fine if the default value is 0, but since they're mostly 1s, I lose the benefit of using a SparseArray.

Comment: That is a bug and I filed it as such. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: As a side note, once can use s["Background"] to get access to the background element.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a straightforward way to set that? `s[[3]]=1` doesn't work, of course--it sets the third element of the notional array s represents.

Comment: @LeonAvery you want a workaround to set the background or to set all the elements to a value?

Comment: To set the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in 10.0.2, windows 7, 64 bits

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. :-)